# Improving how a checkbox clears two text fields and the other way around

Tags: javascript

I have two text fields and one checkbox. Basically two things should happen with the code:

1. If you click on the checkbox, both text fields are cleared.
2. If you
   write something in one of the two text fields, the checkbox is
   "unchecked"

I made it happen with the code below, but I am pretty sure that the code is a mess. Is there a more elegant way to tackle the issue?

```
<script>

    document.getElementById('A026_01').onclick = function ClearFields() {       
         document.getElementById('A025_01').value = "";
         document.getElementById('A025_02').value = "";
    }

    document.getElementById('A025_01').onchange = function ClearFields2() {        
         document.getElementById('A026_01').checked = false;            
    }

    document.getElementById('A025_02').onchange = function ClearFields2() {  
         document.getElementById('A026_01').checked = false; 
    }


</script>
```

Comment: why functions have names?

Comment: mostly because I didn't know better and in php you give functions usually names. Mistake from my side.

Comment: you have 2 times the same function name `ClearFields2` - for the second call, just give the first name, without putting the code.
Otherwise, I have the impression that you have not seen my answer lower

Comment: I have seen and tested your answer, works great as well and I appreciate your comments , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **oninput** instead of **onchange** like this:

```js
document.getElementById('A026_01').onclick = function () {

         document.getElementById('A025_01').value = "";
         document.getElementById('A025_02').value = "";
    }


    document.getElementById('A025_01').oninput = function () {

         document.getElementById('A026_01').checked = false;

    }

    document.getElementById('A025_02').oninput = function () {

         document.getElementById('A026_01').checked = false;

    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id ="A025_01">A025_01
  <br>
  <input type="text" id ="A025_02">A025_02
   <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id ="A026_01">A026_01
```

Comment: oninput is a good idea, but you have 2 `ClearFields2` ( same error than OP )

Comment: @MisterJojo, The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed.

Comment: `document.getElementById('A025_02').oninput = ClearFields2;` would have been better

Answer (score 2):

may be this one should please you...

```js
const chkBx = document.getElementById('A026_01')
,     inp_1 = document.getElementById('A025_01')
,     inp_2 = document.getElementById('A025_02')
;

// init
chkBx.checked = false

chkBx.onclick=_=>inp_1.value = inp_2.value = ''
inp_1.oninput=_=>chkBx.checked = false
inp_2.oninput=_=>chkBx.checked = false
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="A026_01" />A026_01 <br>
<input type="text" id="A025_01" />A025_01
<input type="text" id="A025_02" />A026_01
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:
1. Save everything in variables;
2. Clear off data while start typeing (keypress).

```
const checkBox = document.getElementById('A026_01');
const textField1 = document.getElementById('A025_01');
const textField2 = document.getElementById('A025_02');
const unCheck = () => {
    checkBox.checked = false;
};

checkBox.addEventListener('click', () => {
  textField1.value = '';
  textField2.value = '';
});


[textField1, textField2].forEach(textElem => {
  textElem.addEventListener('keypress', unCheck);
});
```